# Playa Re-ordering Not Working

Tags: playa

I have a site that has a custom sidebar for each page and I decided to use Playa to accomplish this. I have the sidebar components displaying on each page as expected but the re-ordering doesn't seem to be working, they just stay in the same order as they are in my template.

Has anyone ever come across this before?

Template code - which is an include on each page:

```
<div class="sidebar">
{exp:channel:entries channel="page|sub_page|news_page|events_page|music_page|gallery_page|shop_page|reviews_page|contact_page" url_title="{embed:parent}"}
    {exp:playa:children field="sidebar" channel="sidebar_image_component"}
    <div class="sidebarComponent">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <a href="{sidebar_image_component_link}" class="linkImage"><img src="{sidebar_image_component_image}" alt="Buy my latest album" /></a>
        <a href="{site_url}/shop" class="siteButton album">Buy Album<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    {/exp:playa:children}
    {exp:playa:children field="sidebar" channel="sidebar_text_component"}
    <div class="sidebarComponent">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        <p>{sidebar_text_component_textarea}</p>
        <a href="{sidebar_text_component_link}" class="siteButton">{link_text}<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
    </div>
    {/exp:playa:children}
    {exp:playa:children field="sidebar" channel="sidebar_featured_music"}
    <div class="sidebarComponent">
        <h4>{title}</h4>
        {sidebar_soundcloud_iframe}
    </div>
    {/exp:playa:children}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: Could you explain a little more about reordering - what you're reordering specifically and what you're doing that's not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Playa can’t re-code your template for you; if your template is first outputting any children from the “sidebar_image_component” channel, then from the “sidebar_text_component” channel, and then from the “sidebar_featured_music” channel, that’s the order they’ll appear in.

If you want the entries to be output in the Playa-defined order, you’ll need to merge all of that into a single {exp:playa:children} tag pair:

```
{exp:playa:children field="sidebar"}
    <div class="sidebarComponent">
        <h4>{title}</h4>

        {if channel_short_name == "sidebar_image_component"}
            <a href="{sidebar_image_component_link}" class="linkImage"><img src="{sidebar_image_component_image}" alt="Buy my latest album" /></a>
            <a href="{site_url}/shop" class="siteButton album">Buy Album<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        {/if}

        {if channel_short_name == "sidebar_text_component"}
            <p>{sidebar_text_component_textarea}</p>
            <a href="{sidebar_text_component_link}" class="siteButton">{link_text}<i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></a>
        {/if}

        {if channel_short_name == "sidebar_featured_music"}
            {sidebar_soundcloud_iframe}
        {/if}

    </div>
{/exp:playa:children}
```

Comment: Thanks for this Brandon, works perfectly. I knew it would be something fairly simple but I am new(ish) to EE and Playa. Thanks again. Stephen.

Comment: No worries! Glad that worked for you :)